# Detach intermediate module in Pytorch with regard to part of the loss

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, gradient-descent

Let's say I have the following forward pass that results in two separate losses:

```python
forward(self, input)
    x = self.layer1(input)

    y = self.layer2(x)

    z = self.layer3(y)

    return y, z
```

We then calculate loss1(y) and loss2(z). Then we can optimize `loss = loss1 + loss2` with a single optimizer.

But I have two caveats: (1) I want d_loss1 to be calculated with regards to layer2 only (without layer1), and (2) I want d_loss2 to be calculated with regards to layer3 and layer1 - without layer2.
Essentially, I want to train non-consecutive parts of the network separately with separate losses.

I believe I can solve (1) by introducing a stop-gradient in the input to layer2 like so:

```python
forward(self, input)
    x = self.layer1(input)

    y = self.layer2(x)
    y_stop_gradient = self.layer2(Variable(x.data))

    z = self.layer3(y)

    return y_stop_gradient, z
```

But how can I solve (2)?
In other words, I want loss2's gradients to "skip" layer2 **while keeping** layer2 trainable with regards to loss1.

Answer (score 0):

While waiting for a proper answer I found one of my own, though it's a terribly inefficient one and I'm hoping for someone else to come up with a better solution.

My solution looks like this:

```
import copy
forward(self, input)
    x = self.layer1(input)

    y = copy.deepcopy(self.layer2)(x)  # create a full copy of the layer
    y_stop_gradient = self.layer2(Variable(x.data))

    z = self.layer3(y)

    return y_stop_gradient, z
```

This solution is inefficient because (1) I think deep copy is overkill for what I'm trying to do and too expensive and (2) the gradients for layer2 relative to z are still calculated, they're just unused.